# Enumerating sql server instances on lan

Tags: c#, sql-server, lan

I'm trying to implement the GUI for choosing MS SQL Server Instance from those available in the network.

Firstly, I tried well-known methods, such as SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers() and SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources(). Both of them do not suffice me, because I want to control the search timeout, and the default timeout is like 30 seconds.

Then I found [another approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12336/Locate-SQL-Server-instances-on-the-local-network): broadcasting UDP datagram over the LAN to get response from live SQL Server instances. I can set whatever timeout I want, and it seems that setting 1 second timeout is more than enough.

The only problem here though is that this method doesn't return me the same amount of records as library methods do. It seems like scanning the network is not the only action that these methods perform. I looked into the source code using ILDasm, but I only figured out that the main part of functionality is hidden somewhere in native code.

Can someone explain me what happens in these methods?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @kostasch. how does one provide code, if the question is "what are the things I don't know about" ?

Comment: @MarcGravell you r right, i didn't notice the codeproject link. I will delete the comment

Comment: Ok, here is the [code](https://gist.github.com/kosmakoff/7449760), try it on your environment. In my environment there is plenty of servers. First method finds 49 instances, while second method finds only 15. Basically, second method returns a subset of instances that are returned by first method. My question is: where does first method take all remaining items?